# What is the word to describe the lack of something?

Tags: synonyms

You have suffered many hardships and lived ...." (the term I want to find is here, it's like people live under poor conditions and don't have many facilities, lack of something to support their daily lives. What word should I use to describe that situation?)

Comment: "Poverty" can be applied in many ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions:

"lived *without*..."

"lived *in lack of*..."

"lived *bereft of*..."

"lived *in deprivation*..."

More directly emphasising poverty:

"lived in *poverty*..."

"lived in *penury*..."

"lived *destitute*..."

Comment: 'Penuriously' meets OP's semantic requirements, but I'm not suggesting it as a reasonable choice. Your prepositional phrases are far more idiomatic.

Comment: Also, *in want*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I’m sure the same people who trashed the paediatrician’s office would also snigger quite sillily at _penuriously_, assuming it to be a descriptor of someone with rather too many male reproductive appendages in their life.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for **"humbly"**

"You have suffered many hardships and lived *humbly*"

> humbly (adv)
>
> humble (adj)  low in importance, status, or condition: a humble home. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/humble), of low social, administrative, or political rank. [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/humble)
>
> - "He came from a humble, unprivileged background". [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/humble)
> - "She's not ashamed of her humble beginnings."
>     [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humble)

Answer (score 0):

You could say the person lived *simply*, which does not mean they were necessarily bothered by the ascetic conditions, and may even have been a deliberate choice.

Comment: I didn't get the sense that it was a voluntary choice from the OP's question, but if that's what was intended, then better choices would have been "lived a *spartan* existence" or "lived an *austere* life".

Answer (score 0):

"...lived a **hand-to-mouth existence".**

"...lived **hand-to-mouth".**

"...lived **never knowing where the next meal was coming from".**

"...lived **like paupers".**

"...and **could scarcely make ends meet".**